# How to pass Array to JQuery Ajax Post?

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, post, input

I have the following in a form

`<input type="text" class="attr_values[]" value="1" />
<input type="text" class="attr_values[]" value="2" />`

And I am trying to pass all the values in the "attr_values" array so it can be posted via Ajax but the following doesn't work.

```
$.ajax({   
   url: 'index.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data:{ 
      attr_values: $('.attr_values').val()
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Why are you providing `[]` to class name?

Comment: I think might not have understood the purpose of the `[]` with form elements. Have a look at the PHP documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to set name attribute for all input elements and remove `[]` from class attribute, which is absolutely wrong uses of classes:

```
<input type="text" name="attr_values[]" class="attr_values" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="attr_values[]" class="attr_values" value="2" />
```

Then, serialize input values using jQuery as:

```
var __data = $('input[name^="attr_values"]').serialize();
// Or if input has parent form
var __data = $('#form-id').serialize();

$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: __data
```

Comment: I had tried with name=attr_values[] but I guess I was forgetting about the input[name=] in jquery.. but using this I get: attr_values%5B%5D=1&attr_values%5B%5D=2 and I want in fact only 1,2

Comment: So, you can comma separate values: `var e = $('input[name^="attr_values"]');
var v=new Array(e.length);
e.each(function(i,j){
  v[i]=j.value;
});
v.join(",");`

OR do `implode(',', $_POST['attr_values'])` on server side

Comment: By doing this it worked
`var attrs = new Array();
$('input[name^="attr_values"]').each(function() {
 attrs.push($(this).val());
}); 
var attrs_combined = attrs.join(); 

$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: attrs_combined
`

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var = $( '#your_form_id_or_class' ).serialize() ;

and assign this to **attr_values**
```

ref : https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a wildcard selector:

```
$('input[name^="attr_values"]').serialize();
```

The selector above will find every `<input>` who's name starts with attr_values and serialize it for you so you would simply do:

```
data: $('input[name^="attr_values"]').serialize(),
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not need `[]` in for your input element class name

```
<input type="text" class="attr_values" value="1" />
<input type="text" class="attr_values" value="2" />
```

You don't need to use [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) jQuery API

If value passes to the `data` parameter of [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting.

```
var attrValueArray = $("input.attr_values").map(function(){
  return this.value;
}).get();

$.ajax({   
   url: 'index.php',
   type: 'POST',
   data:{ 
      attr_values: attrValueArray
```

Comment: this doesn't work. it doesn't return anything